# Snapping to hours in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

With *pandas 0.8.0*,

```
import pandas
import pandas.tseries.offsets
h = pandas.tseries.offsets.Hour()
times = pandas.date_range(start='2010-1-1 1:00:05', periods=3, freq='3H')
times
```

> [2010-01-01 01:00:05, ..., 2010-01-01 07:00:05]
>   Length: 3, Freq: 3H, Timezone: None

```
times.snap(h)
```

> [2010-01-01 01:00:05, ..., 2010-01-01 07:00:05]
>   Length: 3, Freq: H, Timezone: None

This is because:

```
h.onOffset(times[0])
```

> True

I'd guess that this functionality is pretty new, it doesn't seem to be documented much.

> The rollforward and rollback methods do exactly what you would expect:

My larger goal here is using 2 frequencies (e.g. 4 hours and 1 day) and bucketing a series of timestamps based on the first frequency modulo the second (e.g. 7:05:33 -> 1, 19:59:59 -> 4, 21:44:00 -> 5)

Comment: I have no idea but I just wanted to say this is the best sounding question title ever.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, here's my implementation of snapping 30 second data:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Tick
from pandas.tslib import Timedelta


class HalfMinute(Tick):
    _inc = Timedelta(seconds=30)

    def _snap_delta(self, dt):
        d = Timedelta(seconds=dt.second, microseconds=dt.microsecond)
        if d >= self._inc:
            d -= self._inc
        return d

    def onOffset(self, dt):
        return not self._snap_delta(dt)

    def rollforward(self, dt):
        return dt + (self._inc - self._snap_delta(dt))

    def rollback(self, dt):
        return dt - self._snap_delta(dt)


def test_snap():
    from random import random
    from datetime import timedelta
    # 1 hour of test data
    grid_index = pd.date_range('2015-09-09 00:00:00', '2015-09-09 01:00:00', freq='30S')

    # add uniform noise of maximum +-5 seconds
    mess_index = pd.Index(dt + timedelta(seconds=(random() - 0.5) * 10)
                          for dt in grid_index)

    snapped_index = mess_index.snap(HalfMinute())

    assert snapped_index.equals(grid_index)
```

In your case you can do something similar to craft a Offset object.

Answer (score 0):

The Hour DateOffset is "every hour" and not "every hour on the hour".
You can try subclassing Hour to override onOffset.
You can also checkout the TimeSeries.between_time method.